# How to access SQL Server using stored procedure in windows forms application?

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms

In asp.net I have been using the BLL and DAL. I want to know whether I can implement these two layers in windows application or not. I tried to import libraries which I used to import for web applications so that I could use DataSet. But here I am not able to do so . Please tell me the correct way to access database.

```
public DataSet DBQueryWithoutParam(System.Data.CommandType command, string QueryText)
{
   return (db.ExecuteDataSet(command, QueryText));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data access is exactly the same no matter the type of application.  In fact, one of the main reasons that you create separate BLL and DAL is so that you can use them in different types of applications without having to change anything but the UI.  If you're finding that that's not working for you then you didn't build those layers properly because they must have some specific dependency.  I suggest that you ask a new question on how to fix the BLL and DAL that you have to make them truly independent of your presentation layer.  Describe the exact issue, including any error message(s).